# Why are the sum and mul methods returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

Anytime i run the program the alert function returns undefined in both instances

```
const calculator = {
    sum(){
        return this.a + this.b;
    },

    mul(){
        return this.a * this.b;
    },
    read(){
        this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
        this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
    },
   
}

JSON.stringify(calculator.read());
alert(JSON.stringify(calculator.sum));
alert(JSON.stringify(calculator.mul));
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're using `JSON.stringify` for here. If you don't need it, please remove it, towards producing an actual [MCVE].

Comment: Why the calls to `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the functions

```js
const calculator = {
    sum(){
        return this.a + this.b;
    },

    mul(){
        return this.a * this.b;
    },
    read(){
        this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
        this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
    },
   
}

JSON.stringify(calculator.read());
alert(JSON.stringify(calculator.sum()));
alert(JSON.stringify(calculator.mul()));
```